# What does "link to unknown" mean?

Tags: linux, fedora, symbolic-link

I just upgraded my server to Fedora 17 which made a switch of my bootloader from GRUB Legacy to GRUB2. There are two symbolic links in the `/etc` folder that points to the files `grub.conf` and `grub.cfg` in `/boot/grub` and `/boot/grub2` respectively. Though the targets seem correct, the link icons are displaying an X status which seems to indicate that the links are broken. Upon right-clicking the property type, it states "link to unknown". The file size of the link corresponds exactly with the file size of the target file, so, why does the links appear to be broken?

The image of the link icons:

[image]

As requested, the following are the outputs from the commands:

```
$ ls -l /etc/grub.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Jul 14  2011 /etc/grub.conf -> ../boot/grub/grub.conf

$ ls -l /etc/grub2.cfg
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Dec 10 18:57 /etc/grub2.cfg -> ../boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I am looking at the directory, added the image of the link icons for clarity.

Comment: can you please post the output of the following 2 commands? "ls -l /etc/grub.conf" and "ls -l /etc/grub.cfg"

Comment: @WaleedHamra, please see my edit as per your request.

Comment: Your server has a GUI? o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X shows that Nautilus cannot resolve symlink to cfg-files. Most likely you execute Nautilus as a regular user, but config files have 700 security permissions and root as an owner. So you haven't permissions to read grub.cfg and grub.conf.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense some sense to me. So can I say that the X status not just reflects a broken link, but whether the file to which it is linked is accessible to the user?

Comment: I think so. But I never use gui on the server and not very often maintain server as a ordinary user :) Strictly speaking symlink is broken anyway: target is inaccessible. The reason could be absence of the file or security issues.